# Create a flow network from a flow direction ARC GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, hydrology, flow-direction

First, I created a flow_direction from a DEM, then I applied corrections to this flow direction.
Now my question, how to create a flow network (order flow) from a flow direction, that I already corrected?
What tool to use on ARC GIS: ArcToolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools> Hydrology> ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few more steps steps you must take.

1. Use the Flow Accumulation (Spatial Analyst > Hydrology tools) tool to create a flow accumulation grid.
2. Create a stream network using the raster calculator tool (Spatial Analyst > Map Algebra). You should enter a funtion like:

   SetNull("[Flow Accumulation Grid]<[flow accumulation threshold],1)

[brackets] should be substituted with appropriate variables.

You now have a stream network raster. You can use additional tools like Stream Link, Stream Order, and Stream to Feature (all under Spatial Analyst > Hydrology tools) to refine your results.

Comment: Thank you Scott La Vanne for your answer, but I'm stuck in the second step, each time, it makes me an error message!! I use the following formula : SetNull("FlowAcc" < 100,1)   what is the problem that may be encountered

Comment: What is the error message?